# how to search channel youtube with status made-for-kid

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to search list channels with status made-for-kid by keywords. Currently, I only can search by keywords then I use "YouTube.list" to get their status, then filter to get a list made-for-kid. This way makes me waste a lot of queries (quota).

Could you please share your experience with me?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe reverse-engineering the UI of https://www.youtubekids.com/search?q=YOUR_QUERY is the only solution or maybe [`safeSearch`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#safeSearch) may help you.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminLoison, the second idea with SafeSearch, I think it already defaults by YouTube API (with mode "moderate"). Can you please explain more about your first idea? And furthermore, as I understand, YouTube separated the advertising for the standard YouTube (include MFK and normal) and the YouTube Kid, right?

Comment: Note that `safeSearch` can also take the `strict` value. My first idea consists in automatizing search through https://youtubekids.com by reverse-engineering HTTPS packets sent and received. You can analyze them with your `Network` web-browser tab. In fact I don't know much about MFK and https://youtubekids.com Are you aware of any way to filter from the YouTube UI (https://www.youtube.com) MFK videos? Otherwise requesting a quota increase may make sense: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/quota_and_compliance_audits

Comment: Hi @BenjaminLoison, I suppose you meant crawling channel from YouTubeKid right? If we are lucky enough to crawl without banning by GG. Furthermore, we do not know the id or URL exactly of the channel. Regarding the YouTube UI, I can not find the option to target on YouTubeKid, it may require a private deal and some approved policy from GG

Comment: @Peter89 I think there is no direct option, only alternatives. You can keep searching channels using the `search.list` endpoint and then, make another request to `channel.lists` by passing the `channel_id` then, read the `status.madeForKids` value - N.B. not all channels has this value. If it might helps, consider use keywords that those channels has - in order to increase your chances to get the desired results.

Comment: Thanks, @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes, I am doing this way to get the MFK channels